# ChakraUI theme colors not working with boxShadow React

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

In my react project I am trying to apply a `box-shadow` to my input focus state using a custom color from my ChakraUI theme. I noticed the theme color is not being applied.

```
          input: {
            fontSize: 'desktop.body',
            _focus: {
              borderColor: 'theme.dark.background',
              boxShadow: '0 0 0 1px theme.dark.background',
            },
          },
```

I noticed if I set for example: `boxShadow: '0 0 0 1px red',` the style works as expected with the red color.

How can I get my theme color to apply to the box-shadow? Any advice would be great thanks

Comment: what is the actual value of `theme.dark.background`? is it something like `#F08080` or `rgb(240, 128, 128)` ?

Answer (score 2):

`boxShadow: '0 0 0 1px var(--chakra-colors-dark-background)',`